# Google+ sign in button background ridges

Tags: android, xml

I have a project I'm currently working on where the user needs to register & login either through Google+ or Email.

The problem I'm encountering is with the background on the Google+ button that I'm trying to implement.

This is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XthoJ.png

This is how I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfNAJ.png

This is the code for the button:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/btnGooglePlus"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="@string/btnGooglePlus"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnEmail"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I'm very new to android development, so bear with me here.

**EDIT:**

This is the code for the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:label="loginMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    tools:context="com.fridge.myapplication.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main">
    ...
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: well... those are padding/margin post all your layout